# Git - Automatic pulling in server

Tags: linux, git, version-control, debian, hook

I'm desperately trying to prepare a correct environment for a new project. We plan to work locally with Xampp with my team and then push everything on a testing server, so I've started to learn git and its specificities.

When I try to push everything is ok, but then I want my server to automatically pull the updated files where it was cloned. So I created a post-update file which is like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Mise en production..."

cd /home/test/public_html/
unset GET_DIR

git fetch origin master
```

The problem is I get this error

```
remote: Mise en production...
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

Is there a better solution that would be efficient ?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Invest some time into using CI tools like Jenkins and get your CI pipeline up and running to handle the builds.

Comment: You could take a look at Git's hooks - https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks - which can perform actions in different states e.g. pre-commit, post-commit, etc

Comment: @Emil It looks like OP is in fact already using a hook, namely the post-receive one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need that after the local repo changes are pushed to a testing server, then you also want the local changes are pushed to your server. So you can use **post-update hook** to do that:

In the testing server, edit the contents of `hooks/post-update` file as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Mise en production..."
branch=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD | sed -e 's,.*/\(.*\),\1,')
git push -u /path/for/your/server $branch
echo "push to my server "
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted solution works, but you have overlooked one detail.

When changing into `/home/test/public_html/`, you need to realize that this directory is not a Git repository and hence, you cannot fetch into it. To make this work, execute the following once.

```
$ cd /home/test/public_html
$ git init
$ git remote add origin [path/to/git/repo]
```

After that, you'll be able to `git fetch` and `git pull` in `/home/test/public_html`.

The `[path/to/git/repo]` should be a relative or absolute path to the directory that contains your repository. This is the directory that has directories `branches`, `hooks`, `info`, et cetera.

Comment: After avis done this 
`$ cd public_html
$ ls
$ git init
Dépôt Git vide initialisé dans /home/test/public_html/.git/
$ git remote add origin /home/test/.git`

Still got the error : 

`remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'`

Comment: What happens if you execute a fetch or pull in the `public_html` directory? Does that give an error?

Comment: Pulling works fine ! But the automated hook on the original repo sends me a Samuel L. Jackson error!

Comment: Interesting. Which hook are you using exactly? post-receive?

Comment: Can you try post-receive instead?

Comment: Weird, it's not in the hooks directory. Hooray to the unfaitfhul friday !

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Did it help?

Comment: Can you create it? What version of Git are you using?