# Automatic scheduled git pulls on a GCP server running a flask website

Tags: flask, github, githooks

I had a few questions about automatic git pulls on a remote server. I am aware there are several questions like this, but I wasn't sure what steps to take exactly, and I don't want to mess up my current setup with a mistake :/

To wit, the environment is on a Google Cloud VM. I am running a flask-based website that renders each page with the `render_template()` function.

The website resides inside its git folder, i.e. I never set up a bare repo and copied stuff. When I set it up a couple years ago, I just did `git clone repo-url`, then inside the repo directory, did `flask run`. Then I set up nginx to connect to the site's socket created with uwsgi inside the repo directory.

--

It has been working fine. I make changes locally to the content, push to github, then log in to the VM, and perform a `git pull`.

I want to do this automatically. I tried adding a cron job to do this, where the job basically ran a script, and the script did the git pull. Script content was:

```
cd /repo
git pull
```

Running the script in the server worked, but cron never managed to do the pull.

--

I have been reading about web hooks, and there is a bunch of stuff about [post-receive hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394510/setting-up-a-git-hook-to-automatically-git-pull-on-a-remote-server), [post-update hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43540495/git-automatic-pulling-in-server), and making bare repos. At this point, I am embarrassed to say I have no idea what I should be doing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to consider a GitHub Action, which, from GitHub, could interract with your Google cloud VM.

For example, [`actions-hub/gcloud`](https://github.com/actions-hub/gcloud).

```yaml
- uses: actions-hub/gcloud@master
  env:
    PROJECT_ID: test
    APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS }}
  with:
    args: cp your-file.txt gs://your-bucket/
    cli: gsutil
```